# Is there a way to combine tailwind selectors?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want add a class based on the checked state of the checkbox on a child of a peer element

placing `peer-checked:` works on the parent div not the child div

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" className='hidden peer' />
    <div className='bg-blue-main rounded-full w-[3.125rem] h-[1.125rem] p-[1px] relative peer-checked:bg-black peer-checked:'>
        <div className='bg-white h-full aspect-square rounded-full shadow-md absolute top-0 left-0 peer-checked:first:bg-red-500'></div>
    </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) that applies when a parent element's previous sibling with a `peer` class is checked:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class='hidden peer' />
  <div class='bg-blue-main rounded-full w-[3.125rem] h-[1.125rem] p-[1px] relative peer-checked:bg-black peer-checked:'>
    <div class='bg-white h-full aspect-square rounded-full shadow-md absolute top-0 left-0 [.peer:checked~*_&]:bg-red-500'></div>
  </div>
</label>
```

You could also abstract this into [a variant via a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants).